# How do i fetch a specific string from a file with _applicationObject

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Im making a visual studio add-in and one of its functions need to check if a specific string inside the solution file exists.
Im using C#.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Find property of DTE2.

Take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/44de0117.aspx